# Can a class have a "Has-a" relationship with a String?

Tags: oop, aggregation, composition

All the discussions I've seen regarding Is-a and Has-a relationships refer to examples of user-defined types.

In the below code, can it be said that Flommer has-a String ?

```
class Flommer extends Flimmer {
    String s = "hey";
}
```

Comment: Yes. It's not particularly useful to say that, but yes.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of OOP the two relationship types, **aggregation**(HAS-A) and **composition**(OWNS-A) are similar but subtly different.

Aggregation is when the contained object can exist on it's own outside of the container object.
***Real life ex***: Car and Engine objects. An Engine can exist by itself outside of the Car, as Cars may get a different Engine when the first one breaks etc.

Composition is when the container controls/*owns* the lifetime of the contained object. That is when the container does not exist, the contained object does not make sense to exist also.
***Real life ex***: House and Room objects. You can't just have a Room by itself in the field, you need to have it in the house to make sense. When a House gets destroyed you also destroy the Rooms.

In your concrete example I would say that you have a *composition* relationship, since `s`(the contained object) seems to be a private field of `Flommer` and it gets a value inline (created by the `Flommer`).

If you can think of a "real-life" concept that makes sense to exist outside of 'Flommer' and can be represented as a simple `string` then you will have a HAS-A relationship. So it is dependent on what **real** concepts are you trying to model and how you create the object model. Until then you have a OWNS-A relationship i.e. composition.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. String and the other user-defined types you mention all inherit from the Object class. So in a sense, they're similar.

Answer (score -1):

```
In the above code, can it be said that Flommer has-a String ?
```

**Yes**, it is having Has-a relationship - So you can implement composition with this.

Consider an example,

Student is-a person

Student has-a name(say String name ="John")

By Composition, you get the name of the student(which has `has-a` relationship) **OP question is answered here**

By Inheritance(Inheriting `Flommer`), you still get the name of the student(in which you acquire entire state and behavior of `Flommer` but not in Composition)

Both composition and inheritance can be used for code reuse.

[This](https://thenewcircle.com/static/bookshelf/java_fundamentals_tutorial/object_oriented.html) post will be of good help in understanding the concept better

Comment: Related to inheritance you can only say that `Flommer` IS-A `Flimmer`. Where is the connection with the `s` variable that the question was about?

Comment: @LiviuM. Edited my post. I was meaning to say you can get `s` by inheriting too. btw i answered with `Yes`too :)

Comment: @Downvoter Please tell me wat's wrong in ma answer, so that i can improve or correct it